# C++: contigouos memory for polymorphic objects

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, polymorphism, stdvector

I'm currently working on a multiplayer board game and manage the playing fields using a simple `std::vector<T>`.
However, I don't store the concrete objects in the vector, but only the pointers to these field objects.
In the C/C++ literature or on the Internet I often find that this shouldn't be so good (for reasons of performance --> a lot of cache misses ).
I realize that this doesn't give me a linear, contiguous memory area, but rather the fields/objects are scattered somewhere in memory.

However, I don't know how I can solve this better.
Especially since the fields are polymorphic.
In other words, I have a base class cField from which the specialized subtypes of fields inherit.

In my source code it looks like this:

```
class cField 
{
public:
    uint8_t         m_pos{ 0 };
    std::string     m_name{};
}

class cSpecialField : cField
{
public:
private:
}

class cEventField : cField
{
public:
private:
}


// vector, which manage the memory for all board fields
std::vector< std::unique_ptr<cField> > m_fields;
```

The question I'm asking is how I can ensure that the memory area stays contigouos and I don't lose the polymorphism.
From the Game Controller perspective, the base class cField serves as an interface through which I can access the generic methods that all fields have in common. I can easily iterate over all fields etc.

Could `std::variant<T>` be the solution?
That it goes like this, for example:

```
std::vector< std::variant<cSpecialField , cEventField> > m_fields
```

But I read somewhere that a lot of storage space might be wasted because the vector then uses the largest data type of the variant for each element.
That's not ideal either...

Thank you very much!!

Comment: You may be putting the cart before the horse. Before you optimize you need to profile so you know where the hotspots are and you can focus your efforts on those. You also need that as a baseline so you know if you are making things better or worse. That assumes that you actually have performance issues in the first place which you may not. An unoptimized finished game can always be optimized but a game never finished due to analysis paralysis might be amazingly fast but it also isn't finished.

Comment: The example you show is not very good if the question is about polymorphism, because there's no polymorphism in it.

Comment: you want to look into ECS systems, the way this usually works is that you separate your objects into components, and you iterate over the components, not lump everything into a single object, because different objects may have the same components.

Comment: The video game industry tends to use [Entity-Component Systems (ECS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) to solve this problem. You should really avoid having pointers of polymorphic object. Usual POO approaches are a disaster for performance (actually one could argue that this is even POO itself). With ECS, entities can be stored as multiple arrays each one having a fixed type and sorted for fast accesses. This significantly reduce cache misses.

Comment: By the way, if `m_name` is not small, `std::string` will store the actual string buffer not contiguously in memory introducing another indirection. Small fixed-size strings should be preferred instead. Also, please note that in this specific case, `std::variant` is not so bad since the objects should have the same size anyway. Besides, [Data-oriented design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-oriented_design) is also a key to reduce cache-misses (quite related to ECS since efficient modern ECS ones also use this approach too).

Comment: @heapunderrun Funny. I meant OOP but I missed the order of letters in English is reversed compared to French (my native language). I am not sure OOP smell better than POO ;) .